# Windows 8 License Information

Tags: windows-8, licensing, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows 8 App which I want to put in the store now. The AppSimulator works fine (even though I can't set the IsActive to 'true' when I click on 'OK'... But the MsgDialog 'Thanks' pops up), but I don't know if the CurrentApp is correct. I've already read that the IsActive will be set to true automatically without assigning it in the code.

I just have two questions regarding the code below:

1. Will the code for the CurrentApp work?
2. Since I don't assign anything in the WindowsStoreProxy.xml when it comes to CurrentApp, because Windows is loading this information automatically from the store (don't know if it's true... I've read it somewhere), how can I say that the ProductLicenses is called 'Premium' in the WindowsStoreProxy.xml ? It's easy in the CurrentAppSimulator, because it's loading the prices/name/... from my internal XML-file in-app-purchase.xml, but how to set the XML-file for the real App? In the Windows Store?

---

```cs
#if DEBUG
    StorageFolder proxyDataFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("data");
    StorageFile proxyFile = await proxyDataFolder.GetFileAsync("in-app-purchase.xml");
    licenseChangeHandler = new LicenseChangedEventHandler(InAppPurchaseRefreshScenario);
    CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation.LicenseChanged += licenseChangeHandler;
    await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(proxyFile);
#endif

#if DEBUG
    LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
    ListingInformation productListing = await CurrentAppSimulator.LoadListingInformationAsync();
#else
    LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
    ListingInformation productListing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
#endif

ProductLicense productLicense = licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["Premium"];  
if (!productLicense.IsActive)       
{       
    Buy()
}
else
{
    //use full function
}

private async void Buy()
{
        #if DEBUG
            LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
        #else
            LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
        #endif
        if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["Premium"].IsActive)
        {
            try
            {
                #if DEBUG
                    await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("Premium", false);
                #else
                    await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("Premium", false);
                #endif
                if (licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["Premium"].IsActive)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("Thanks for buying the app.");
                        await msgDialog.ShowAsync();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("The purchase was cancelled.");
                    await msgDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("Connection error.");
                msgDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("You already have this feature.");
            await msgDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not set it through code. CurrentAppSimulator does it automatically.

Just check your setting in the WindowsStoreProxy.xml and ensure that 'IsTrial' is set 'false'-

```xml
<LicenseInformation>
    <App>
        <IsActive>true</IsActive>
        <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
    </App>
    <Product ProductId="1">
        <IsActive>false</IsActive>
    </Product>
</LicenseInformation>
```